# SQL Arithmetics with unique cells of tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables (using PostgreSQL) which look about the following:

Table 1 (ppoints from 1 to 450 incrementing by 1)

```
--------+-------+--------+---------+---------+-------+
 ppoint | tom08 | tom920 | tom2135 | tom3650 | tom51 |
--------+-------+--------+---------+---------+-------+
 1      | 2.5   | 125    | 52.5    | 15      | 2.5   |
 ...    | ...   | ...    | ...     | ...     | ...   |
 450    | 0     | 7.5    | 87.5    | 0       | 0     |
--------+-------+--------+---------+---------+-------+
```

Table 2

```
--------+-------+
 ppoint |  tom  |
--------+-------+
 1      | 197.5 |
 ...    | ...   |
 450    | 95    |
--------+-------+
```

Table 2's "tom" column is the sum of the Table 1 "tom..." values.

Thing is I want to divide every "tom..." cell from Table 1 from the corresponding summarized value of Table 2.

I've got one value using the following:

```
SELECT
    (SELECT tom08 FROM Table1 WHERE ppoint = 1)/
    (SELECT tom FROM Table 2 WHERE ppoint = 1)
    FROM Table1 WHERE ppoint = 1
```

But it's still only one value and I want to divide every cell with the corresponding Table2 summarized value and put them into a new table (overwriting Table1 is also an option).

This new table's row 1 (with column 1 being the corresponding "ppoint") should contain:

```
tom08 (FROM Table1 WHERE ppoint=1)/tom (FROM Table2 WHERE ppoint=1)
tom920 (FROM Table1 WHERE ppoint=1)/tom (FROM Table2 WHERE ppoint=1)
tom2135 (FROM Table1 WHERE ppoint=1)/tom (FROM Table2 WHERE ppoint=1)
tom3650 (FROM Table1 WHERE ppoint=1)/tom (FROM Table2 WHERE ppoint=1)
tom51 (FROM Table1 WHERE ppoint=1)/tom (FROM Table2 WHERE ppoint=1)
```

This new table's row 2 should contain:

```
tom08 (FROM Table1 WHERE ppoint=2)/tom (FROM Table2 WHERE ppoint=2)
tom920 (FROM Table1 WHERE ppoint=2)/tom (FROM Table2 WHERE ppoint=2)
tom2135 (FROM Table1 WHERE ppoint=2)/tom (FROM Table2 WHERE ppoint=2)
tom3650 (FROM Table1 WHERE ppoint=2)/tom (FROM Table2 WHERE ppoint=2)
tom51 (FROM Table1 WHERE ppoint=2)/tom (FROM Table2 WHERE ppoint=2)
```

And so on until 450, so the final table should look something like this with the following :

```
+--------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| ppoint |    tom08    |   tom920    |   tom2135   |   tom3650   |    tom51    |
+--------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|      1 | 0.012658228 | 0.632911392 | 0.265822785 | 0.075949367 | 0.012658228 |
|     ...| ...         | ...         | ...         | ...         | ...         |
|      2 | 0           | 0.078947368 | 0.921052632 | 0           | 0           |
+--------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

Is there some sort solution for this? Do you have any suggestions?
Sorry for my English - this was probably not the best way to explain my problem :)
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, I think this is what you are looking for.

```
SELECT tom08/tom, tom920/tom, tom2135/tom, tom3650/tom, tom51/tom  
FROM table1 t1, table2 t2 
WHERE t1.ppoint = t2.ppoint;
```

Comment: It's working, thanks!
I also added the ppoint column:
`SELECT t1.ppoint, tom08/tom, tom920/tom, tom2135/tom, tom3650/tom, tom51/tom  
FROM table1 t1, table2 t2 
WHERE t1.ppoint = t2.ppoint;`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a join:

```
SELECT tom08/tom as tom08, tom920/tom as tom930, tom2135/tom as tom2135, tom3650/tom as tom2135, tom51/tom as tom51  
FROM table1
JOIN table2 ON table1.ppoint = table2.ppoint;
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid an expensive `join` do it from the original table

```
select
    ppoint,
    tom08 / tom as tom08,
    tom920 / tom as tom920,
    tom2135 / tom as tom2135,
    tom3650 / tom as tom3650,
    tom51 / tom as tom51
from (
    select *,
        tom08 + tom920 + tom2135 + tom3650 + tom51 as tom
    from table1
) s
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    t1.ppoint,
    t1.tom08/ t.tom tom08,
    t1.tom920/ t.tom tom920,
    t1.tom2135/ t.tom tom2135,
    t1.tom3650/ t.tom tom3650,
    t1.tom51/ t.tom tom51
FROM table1 t1
JOIN(SELECT ppoint, tom FROM table2)t ON t.ppoint = t1.ppoint;
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5ee4f/1)